# Prestashop - change product image on color selection

Tags: html, web, content-management-system, prestashop

I'm doing some edits on a site that has prestashop installed. Now I've eddited the product colors but now the product image is not changing when selecting different colors. Can anyone tell me how can I set it again so the procuts image changes as I select different colors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved trough combinations. You have to assign a specific image to every combination you create.

Products-> Select your product -> left side menu -> Combinations -> new combination

BR's

Comment: can we change the product name on the color change ?

Comment: @Bhawin This requires coding